# Get bbox of ee.Image and not the global coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, extents, geemap

I am trying to get the extent of an ee.Image object. The image is result of reduced collection.

I was trying to do this as following:

```
bbox = img.geometry().bounds().getInfo()["coordinates"]

>>>
[[[-180, -90], [180, -90], [180, 90], [-180, 90], [-180, -90]]]
```

The problem is that the result are always the global coordinates.
I know that the image itself is not global, I have visualize it , and I also understand [based on this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331271/getting-geometry-properties-of-an-ee-image), that it might be **the result of having reduced collection**.
In the post the suggestion is to take the first image, however I wonder if there is other way to get this information, as in my case I can't access it from the first image in the collection.

**My end goal is to be able to get the real coordinates of ee.Image**

**Edit**: just for more information, when I try to take the first image from the collection I get the same global coordinates:

```
col.first().geometry().bounds().getInfo()["coordinates"]

>>>[[[-180, -90], [180, -90], [180, 90], [-180, 90], [-180, -90]]]
```

But the image seems to be NOT global:
[image]

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example? Your code seems right, so probably the issue is caused by either the properties of the image collection or the reduced image.